# Automatically save and load using

Tags: ios

I asked this question earlier and closed it thinking i got the answer, my mistake [Save Values AUTOMATICALLY with NSuserDefaults][1] was not the answer i was looking for.

I need to save and load data permanently when viewing a view controller, i have been using nsuserdefaults for a long time however now i don't want the user to have to click "Save" and "Load" buttons. I would like the application to save the data each time values have been changed and load the new values when the user goes back to the page.

According to what i have read i could use core data or a sqlite database, however it seems to much work to just save two text fields.

There must be another easy way around this.

```
-(IBAction)savedata:(id)sender; {

NSString *savestring = _textview.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"];
[defaults synchronize];  }

- (IBAction)loaddata:(id)sender; {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"FirstTextFieldKey"];
[_textview setText:loadstring]; }
```

currently this is what i have and am using it with a button, but obviously i don't want a button and would like it to save when i leave that view controller and load when i enter the view controller.

Comment: Anything wrong with using the view controller's view "appear"/"disappear" methods?

Comment: well I'm trying that at the moment however still no luck.

Comment: I am using appear/disappear however when i change views the data deletes.

Comment: I'll make a wild guess that the data is not doing the deleting, rather something else is deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the application to save the data each time values have been changed and load the new values when the user goes back to the page.

I'm going to provide you the **Swift** version, the Obj-C version is semantically the same, I'm sure you know how to write the code in Obj-C, if not, please let me know... (I noticed you use Obj-C only after I wrote the Swift code and well my Obj-C has become rusty those days... apologies).

*As I don't really know if you are using `UITextView` or `UITextField`, I'm going to provide versions for both of them (they are pretty similar...).*

In order to save values when they change in the text field/view, you'll have to hook into the events the `UITextField`/`UITextView` emits when its text value changes. You can do this by making your view controller the `UITextFieldDelegate`/`UITextView`.

If you are using `UITextField`:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

  var _textview : UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _textview.delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    // this is called after the textfield loses focus
    // NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(textField.text, forKey: "textfield_value")

  }

  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // this is called whenever the textfield's text changes
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(textField.text, forKey: "textfield_value")
    return true

  }

}
```

If you are using `UITextView`:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

  var _textview : UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _textview.delegate = self
  }

  func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    // this is called after the textfield loses focus
    // I would not recommend this, but it should work as well in here
    // NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(textView.text, forKey: "textview_value")
    return true

  }

  func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    // this is called whenever the textview's text changes
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(textView.text, forKey: "textview_value")
  }

}
```

There are two delegate methods I used for both `UITextView` and `UITextField`, one that triggers on each text change, and one after the text field loses focus. Whether you want to save to user defaults after each modification is up to you (I wouldn't recommend it, but there certainly are use-cases for it ...). I would only save the data when the textfield loses focus (I'm not 100% sure whether the textfield loses focus if you exit the app, but I think it should, so this should also be save to save your data).

Save the value of the text field in one of those methods and you should be good to go...

And also make sure you load the data from `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _textview.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("textfield_text") as! String

    _textview.delegate = self
  }
```

---

## Objective-C

In your `ViewController.h`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textview;

@end
```

In your `ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation ViewController 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  [_textview setText:[defaults valueForKey:@"textfield_text"]];
  [_textview setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setValue:textField.text forKey:@"textfield_text"];
  [defaults synchronize];

}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but could you show me in obj c.

Comment: Do you use a `UITextField` or `UITextView` ?

Comment: I have used UITextField

Comment: for some reason there still nothing loading in the textfield, i enter data into the field switch to another controller come back and its still empty.

Comment: How do you "switch" between controllers ?

Comment: Can you verify that `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called by putting a `NSLog` statement into `textFieldDidEndEditing` ?

Comment: It seems that it is not being called because i did not receive anything in the logs.

Comment: See my edit in `viewDidLoad` you have to set the delegate for the textfield.

Comment: you went above and beyond to help me understand i appreciate it.